# Youtube suggested queries auto complete API for Java / Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i am searching for a API which can give suggested queries for auto complete in YouTube. Is there any API for Java or Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [autocomplete box in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) but you need to give a data source or service, but YouTube API doesn't have a service to return auto completes.
You can use: http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&ds=yt&q=Query

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here i got some link to retrieve data http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&ds=yt&q=Query. It's working fine.

Comment: Thanks, updating my answer with yours then.

Comment: You are always welcome Ibrahim. I know little bit about you. You are the only one guy who can answer the questions related to YouTube industriously.... :D

Comment: we are not getting data in json , it is downoading in .txt file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want JSON back add these parameters. Replace **query** with your query

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q=query&format=5&alt=json